# Who is mucking about with the appearance of this site and why?

Tags: discussion

What on earth is this ghastly nonsense in aid of?

[image: Ghastly nonsense 1]

And this?

[image: Ghastly nonsense 1]

There’s enough junk on SE Biology without the management contributing too.

Comment: Probably something more for the main meta. You can turn it off with the "time travel" link in the upper right that you highlighted in your first image. Seems to be SE's April Fools. I agree with you in that it's a particularly annoying and not at all entertaining instantiation of such a joke.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326022/please-dont-repeat-such-an-intrusive-full-design-aprils-fools-in-the-years-t

Comment: OK. I got it myself. Long past noon here though.

Comment: I thought the actual redesign that recently occurred was enough of a joke.

Comment: @David I think it began for people everywhere when it was `2019-Apr-01 00:00:00` in the earliest possible timezone anywhere on Earth, to maximize our "shared experience" and so it probably ended somewhere around `2019-Apr-02 00:00:00` at the last possible time zone on Earth. At least they didn't bring the dastardly Windows paperclip back again. I found that one particularly traumatizing.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like it, but the lack of `<blink>` tags is disturbing

Comment: They wouldn’t render on modern browsers. The magic dust is their 21st century replacement.